# Set image from app as wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have developed an app which have few images in it. I have placed them in drawable folder. I want to give an option for the users to choose anyone of those images and make it as device's wallpaper. How can I do that? Should the user store it first to gallery and then make it as wallpaper?

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this tutorial will help you: 
http://mobile-development-tutorial.blogspot.ru/2012/12/android-set-wallpaper-programmatically.html

Answer (score 0):

You should let the users choose, and their decision should be placed in a variable. So if users choose #1, the wallpaper1 will be in the background of the xml. If users choose #3, wallpaper3 will be in the background of the xml. So you define 'backgroundwallpaper' in your xml, and define that by using a variable.

Comment: Hi Menno, I am not looking for the background of the xml, I want to set image as device's wallpaper.